# Amazon Web Service Deploy one Application to Several EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, eclipse, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I have recently started using the AWS EC2 service and have deployed my application to a single EC2 instance. The EC2 instance and the load balancer were created automatically by eclipse. I want to deploy the same application to multiple instances at the same time, does anyone know how I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are after Elastic Beanstalk.
You can either upload application via an S3 bucket or push just the changes with GIT (aws.push command)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-branch-environment.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could i simply deploy the same application to the same environment multiple times to create different instances?

Comment: Yes. You can switch between multiple versions. Amazon console gives you access to all previous versions in a nice list. You can switch back and forth between versions you want. However, this won't create new instance. If you are planning to increase number of instances, simply change the configuration (minimum number of servers)